# Openstack sahara: sahara dashboard

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to install Sahara in OpenStack(Pike version).

I adapted the installation from here https://picoledelimao.github.io/blog/2017/01/25/how-to-install-sahara-and-sahara-dashboard-on-openstack-newton/
 and I followed the below steps

1. Create and configure sahara database
2. Create an openstack sahara user, service and endpoints
3. Installation of sahara
4. Configurationf of sahara.conf
5. Change max connection parameter in mysql/my.cnf from 16M to 256M
6. Restart mysql service
7. Restart sahara-api and sahara-engine
8. Installation of sahara dashboard
9. Manage the saharadashboard and openstack dashboard files
10. Restart apache2
11. Open the dashboard and verify the presence of data processing

In the last step, I see the data-processing but I have a lot of error. For example `Error: Unable to fetch node group template list`. I think it is due to the absence of plugin and cluster template.

Can someone explain me how to add them to Sahara?

Comment: When I open the cluster, I see the following errors :                     Error: Unable to fetch cluster list

Error: Unable to fetch cluster template list

                                                                                                      
Error: Unable to fetch node group template list

Error: Unable to retrieve image list

Comment: Do you have the glance service installed?